# How to promote a leader in ectd Election API go client

Tags: go, etcd

I am writing a HA solution for a database; for leader election I am using etcd and interfacing with it using its go client Election API: https://pkg.go.dev/go.etcd.io/etcd/client/v3/concurrency#Election

**NOTE: this is not to be confused with ectd cluster leader election. This is just using etcd as mean to elect a leader for other systems**, example Patroni

[image]

To elect a leader I simply do the following:

```
import (
   clientv3 "go.etcd.io/etcd/client/v3"
   "go.etcd.io/etcd/client/v3/concurrency"
   ....
)

func main {
  ...
  id := uuid.V4()
  e := concurrency.NewElection(my_session, "/leader/")
  go e.Campaign(ctx, id)
  
  for {
    leader, _ := e.Leader(ctx)
    if leader.Kvs[0].Value == id {
      print("I am the leader")
    } else {
      print("I am the replica")
    }

    time.Sleep(30*time.Seconds)
  }
}
```

This works fine, if I start multiple processes of the same application and stop the leader, another one will be elected automatically (failover); however now I would like to add the possibility to promote an arbitrary process using its `id` (switchover).
**Switchover - this is when you manually trigger switch of the leader to one of the replicas and bring the old leader as a new replica into the cluster**.

I have dig into their source code: https://pkg.go.dev/go.etcd.io/etcd/client/v3/concurrency#Election

the API is quite limited, the method `ResumeElection` signature seems to suggest that I can assign an arbitrary leader key, however is not explained how it works.
The `Proclaim` method also seem to do what I am looking for, however it just changes the value of the current leader.

Comment: Please, clarify what do you want to achieve? What do you mean by "possibility to promote an arbitrary process using its id"?

Comment: As written in my question, the technical term is `switchover`: switchover is when you manually trigger switch of the leader to one of the replicas and bring the old leader as a new replica into the cluster.